# VueJS and Laravel: DELETE Request turns into MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to make a DELETE Request to my Laravel API.

I have a todo-App and a tasks.js with a **removeTask** Method that gets the **task object** passed as an argument.

```
removeTask: function(task)
{
    this.tasks.$remove(task);

    this.$http.delete('/api/tasks', { task, 'method': 'DELETE' });
},
```

Here is what I get in my chrome-dev-tools:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Screenshot]

And this is the destroy Method on my TasksController:

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
    return response()->json(Input::all());
}
```

Where exactly am I going wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I have a resourceful route looking like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.tasks.index');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
});
```

Comment: You need a route set up in your routes file. do you have this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in the **removeTask** method with Vue:

```
removeTask: function(task)
{
    this.tasks.$remove(task);

    this.$http.delete('/api/tasks', { task, 'method': 'DELETE' });
},
```

Should have had this:

```
removeTask: function(task)
{
    this.tasks.$remove(task);

    this.$http.delete('/api/tasks/' + task.id, task);
},
```

Didn't pass in the id, like my resourceful route suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Set a route in laravel's `routes.php` file like this:

```
Route::delete('api/tasks', 'TasksController@destroy');
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a route. Found the problem. Had forgot to pass the id to the route. Works like charm now.